# Include external dependencies in a .lib project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

For example I have a solution containing three projects a Core, Editor and Engine. both the Engine and Editor projects are dependent of the Core. Currently I'm bulding the core as an .lib then the Editor and the Engine include the .lib. Which is working perfectly.

But the core depends on third party libraries I can't seem to include any external dependencies due to that the linker tab disappear when changing Configuration Type to Static Library(dll) on the Core project. How should I address this problem?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This is trivial to do, just a the .lib files to your project and they will automatically be merged into the final .lib.  You leave no breadcrumbs to guess what you could do wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You should include all dependencies and build it all together. If they are either dynamic or static libraries.