# How to include external library in your lib?

Tags: c++

I am writing a library which itself uses a header-only 3rd-party library.

Currently, even if I build it as a static library, the client code still needs to add that 3rd-party library as well, as it is declared in my library's header file.

What can I do so that everything that's used by my code, ends up in the static library and the client code doesn't have to include what I have included in the header file?

There was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045113/), but the answer doesn't seem to work for me as I am building the static library with all of its dependencies (i.e. the include paths are configured and builds are successful).

To give you a better view, this is how my `Core.h` looks like:

```cpp
#ifndef CORE_H
#define CORE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/embed.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>
#include <pybind11/functional.h>
#include <pybind11/numpy.h>

namespace py = pybind11;
using namespace py::literals;

typedef void(*CallbackFn)(bool, std::string, py::array_t<uint8_t>&);
typedef std::function<void(std::string)> LogFunction;

class Core
{
private:
    py::scoped_interpreter guard{};
    py::object cls;
    py::object obj;
    py::object startFunc;
    py::object stopFunc;
    py::object setCpuAffinityFunc;
    py::object addCallbackFunc;
    py::object removeCallbackFunc;
    py::object getCallbacksFunc;

    py::dict kwargs;
    py::list callbackList;

public:
    Core();
    Core(bool showFeed);
    ...
```

As you can see, the issue here is the `Pybind11` header-only library which is used in my code. Unfortunately, since these `#include` statements are included in my header file, the client code also needs to add `pybind11` to their project in order for their project to build.

Is there any other way, other than converting all the `py::*` to `void*` and then including the header files in the `Core.cpp` file?

Comment: If they are pointers, it's ok to replace `py::*` by `void*`, but then how can/do you use the class Core?

Comment: @shingo : I'll have to recast them back to py:: what ever they are in the implementation side and carry on. but thats not ideal at all as pybind is a headache in this department as I'm not very familiar with it. so this is the last resort I thinking about

Comment: @Rika Question : you must use only .lib ? No DLLs ? Because DLLs can solve your problem i think

Comment: @Landstalker I can use DLLs as well, actually I should be implementing both cases. but right now I'm having trouble with the static libs. However, I guess I'll be having issues in the DLLs as well. would appreciate if you could explain more how this can be avoided in the dll!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using forward declaration, but not for the `Pybind11` classes. 
This is what I ended up doing :

```cpp
//header file
#ifndef CORE_H
#define CORE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

struct Wapper; 

class Core
{
private:

    Wapper* cls;
    Wapper* obj;
    Wapper* startFunc;
    Wapper* stopFunc;
    ...
public:
    Core();
    ...
};
```

and in the implementation file :

```cpp
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
...

namespace py = pybind11;
using namespace py::literals;

struct Wrapper
{
    py::object obj;
};

py::scoped_interpreter guard{};

Core::Core()
{
    this->cls = new PyWrapper();
    this->obj = new PyWrapper();
    ...
    auto serviceUtilsModule = py::module::import("Module");
    this->cls->obj = serviceUtilsModule.attr("SomeClass");
    ...
    this->obj->obj = this->cls->obj(**kwargs);
    ...
}
```

This hides the pybind11 dependency from the client code and achieves what I was after!

Basically I forward declared a new type, made a pointer out of it and defined it inside the core.cpp. and since I defined in `core.cpp` I have many choices one of which was to add a py::object inside it and use that instead.

Side note:
I noticed the client project had to include `Python`'s `include` and `library` folders or otherwise, it will complain about not finding `Pybind11`! This is truly bizarre! but since the client code will be running in an environment that must have a python package installed, its not an issue! 
However, I'd also like to know why this is happening !

Comment: You took the right approach, but IMHO it's still a bit too granular. I'd see a PIMPL idiom done more like this: https://pastebin.com/EW0YRU7e -- i.e. the publicly facing `Core` just has public member functions, and a single pointer to a forward declared implementation class. All the `Core` member functions just forward parameters to corresponding implementation functions, and the implementation is basically what `Core` was originally.

Comment: Thanks a lot. greatly appreciate your kind and fantastic answers/points :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for you. Consider your case:  Client uses a library which uses a third library.
This can be assimilated by the following solution:

[image]

- `Client : .exe project` is the client who know only `Core project`
- `Core : .lib project` uses ThirdParty (`Header_lib project`) and can be used by `Client project`
- `Header_lib project` is the ThirdParty lib

**Solution configuration:**
 - `Client Project` depend from `Core project`:

[image]

-`Core project` depend from `Header_Lib project`:

[image]

**In code:**

1. `Client` create an instance `cc` of CCore object.
2. `cc` call `useCoreParty` function.
3. `useCoreParty` function uses `ThirdParty`

When i export `core.lib`:

```
DUMPBIN /SYMBOLS   "G:\Core.lib" | findstr "useThirdParty"
```

I get:

[image]

This means that thirdparty part is included in your `core.lib`. Therefore, the client does not need to include thirdpaty's libs

Comment: Thanks a lot. but how does your `core.h` looks like? does it have any method that uses any type from a 3rd party library? this is how my case is. obviously I either have to use forward declaration or `void*` so that my `core.h` doesnt have any signs of the third party library and thus client can include it easily but the library I'm using is a headache when it comes to casts so I'm looking to see if I have any other options. 
I really appreciate your kind help though

Comment: @Rika I moved the code in my `core.h` to make it identical to your case and I updated my post (see first figure).  it doesn't change anything if the code is in my `core.h` or in a `core.cpp` The composition of the librairies remains the same. Hope this will help you

Comment: @Rika *does it have any method that uses any type from a 3rd party library?* yes. it use a class object `CuseThirdParty ObjThirdParty;` and a simple function `useThirdParty ()`

Comment: for my case, there are several classes and types in the 3dparty library that are used as method parameter types, etc and thus that makes the client need to include the 3rdparty header files. or else, the methods types, etc would not be known when it tries to use them.

Comment: @Rika I feel like I missed something ... your Client include for exemple `core.h` and `core.h` include for exemple `3rdParty.h`. why client must include directly `3rdParty.h` ? he inherits it from  `core.h` and this is enough

Comment: my `C++` is rusty, but that was the first thing that came to my mind and this was the first thing I  tried. however, I faced the error and I had to include the pybind include directory to the client project so the error goes away! thats why it made me ask this question in first place. I' love to know if I dont have to do this and find the actual cause if thats really an error on my side !

Comment: @Rika in any case, your project seems to be interested and full of challenges