# How to convert pybind11 object to void*

Tags: c++, pybind11

I'm writing a library where I want to hide the `Pybind11` dependency. Therefore, I want to change all `py::object`s into `void*` in the header which is exposed to clients, and then in the implementation section I convert the `void*` back to the `py::object` it needs to be.

However I noticed doing something like:

```cpp
//tmp.h
private:
// previously py::object module
void* module;
```

```
//tmp.cpp
void tmp::some_func()
{
    this->module = reinterpret_cast<void*>(py::module::import("MyModule")); 
    // and seemingly we cant something like this either
    py::object some_func = reinterpret_cast<py::object>(this->module).attr("some_func");
    ...  
}
```

is not right and fails with the following errors respectively:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2440   'reinterpret_cast': cannot convert from 'pybind11::module' to 'void *'  CoreLib l:\wrapper\wrapper\core.cpp 40  

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2440   'reinterpret_cast': cannot convert from 'void *' to 'pybind11::object'  CoreLib l:\wrapper\wrapper\core.cpp 41
```

How should I go about this conversion ?

Comment: Does py::module::import("MyModule"); return a function or data pointer? You don't want to convert function to data pointer in C++ otherwise use reinterpret_cast. Does not seem like a good design tbh anyway.

Comment: @Chris: they are all objects and yes, reinterpret_cast would be a better option but not here, as it just fails anyway and I just used c style as it was quicker to write for demonstration.

Comment: Can you show the actual error than? I just had a quick look at https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#_CPPv46object and it seems py::object is a kind of smart pointer and there is function py::cast

Comment: @Chris :added the errors to the question

Comment: @Chris: Thanks for the py::cast<>. it works with <void*> but it seems the other way around doesnt work (i.e cant do ```py::object tmp = py::cast<py::object>(this->module);```

Comment: Wouldn't a PImpl idiom be more suitable here? Or interface + factory creating derived classes without actually exposing them to client. | This seems a bit... extreme.

Comment: @DanMašek I actually did that in another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61023948/how-to-include-external-library-in-your-lib/61027166). this was a followup on that, when I needed to expose my class through c api (build my dll using c linkage) so I had to be able to convert between py::object and void* back and forth. I got stuck at the conversion though!

Comment: Ah, I see, I'll comment on that there. | The issue I see here is that ought to be converting "a pointer to `py::object`" to `void*`. So, either you need to take a reference (but then you have to assure the lifetime of the object is long enough), or deal with dynamically allocated `py::object` instances.

Comment: @Rika Here's an illustration of what I meant above: https://pastebin.com/HwFsRWb7

Comment: Thanks alot. really really appreciate it :) why dont you post thatas answer so we can call it a day :)

Comment: No problem, will do that later today, got some work I've got to do first.